# maven-jaxws-tools-plugin Error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss, jax-ws

Swtiching our build from Ant to Maven, I'm trying to generate code from WSDL files.

There is the `maven-jaxws-tools-plugin`, but I always get an Exception. I'm not completely clear on what dependencies this plugin additionally has.

The Plugin config:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
  <configuration>
    <targetPackage>at.dataphone.logis3.wsdl.${projectName}</targetPackage>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <wsdls>
      <wsdl>${basedir}/wsdl/DPHItemBarcodesList.wsdl</wsdl>
    </wsdls>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsconsume</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With no additional deps I get:

> ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ws.api.tools.WSContractConsumer

Then I add:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbossws-native-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

So I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool`

And if I add:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver`

So this goes on and on. But I have the feeling, that I don't want all of these compile time dependencies and that I might need a way to tell the plugin about my JBoss installation with it's modules.

There is only litte documentation for the plugin.

There is this sample: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JAXWSToolsMavenPluginSample

But `jbossws-cxf-client` can't be a dependency, this is old code and uses jbossws-native.
I'm also not sure if the jboss-as-maven-plugin has anything to do with it, but I don't want to deploy, only generate the code. I actaully do have the plugin set-up, although it doesn't work properly. But running `mvn jboss-as:deploy` it still fails at the jaxws-plugin before it can do any deployment.

This example is slightly different, but not much:
https://github.com/tkobayas/example-projects/blob/master/helloworld_jaxws_cxf/pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `maven-jaxws-tools-plugin` but you don't need to add compile-time dependencies: you just need to add those dependencies as [plugin dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
  <configuration>
    <targetPackage>at.dataphone.logis3.wsdl.${projectName}</targetPackage>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <wsdls>
      <wsdl>${basedir}/wsdl/DPHItemBarcodesList.wsdl</wsdl>
    </wsdls>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsconsume</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbossws-native-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This way, those dependencies will only be used during the execution of the plugin and won't be added to your project compile-time dependencies. Of course, this only should be done when your project won't depend on those at compile-time.

You can then add in this tag all the necessary dependencies. For the class `org.jboss.util.xml.JBossEntityResolver`, it looks like the next one on the list is [`jboss-common-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-common-core)...

---

On a side-note, you should maybe consider using the [`cxf-codegen-plugin`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) by from the Apache CXF project.

Comment: Great answer! Adding deps to plugins - that's good to know. In the end, the cxf-codegen-plugin worked way easier. Basically out of the box.